# Using breakpoint analysis to estimate thermocline presence & depth in ponds (r)

Tags: r, statistics, breakpoints, piecewise

Desperate environmental engineering PhD candidate here... (Please forgive formatting issues, etc. - This is my first post!)

**Objective:** In my field study, I measured temperature with pond depth. I want to use these high-frequency data to estimate the depth of my thermocline (if there is one) in r.

**Problem:** In p1, I'd expect the thermocline to occur at about 0.6m below the surface, but my estimated breakpoint doesn't occur at the right depth.

Fig. 1: plot of temperature with depth, shown with decreasing depth on the y-axis to mimic the cross-section of a pond:

[image]

Here's what I've got:

```
fit_glm <- glm(-Vertical.Position.m ~ Temp..C,
               data = data)
seg_fit <- segmented(fit_glm, 
                     seg.Z=~Temp..C, 
                     data=data) 
summary(seg_fit)
```

Which generates the following summary:

Fig. 2: The output of summary(seg_fit) showing the estimated model parameters and breakpoint x-value:

[image]

Yet when I plot using the following code, the breakpoint shown in the resulting plot doesn't make any sense - it looks almost like a perfect mirror image of what I'd expect.

```
plot(data$Temp..C, -data$Vertical.Position.m, pch=16, col='steelblue')

plot.segmented(seg_fit, dens.rug=TRUE, add=TRUE)
```

Fig. 3: Similar to Fig. 1 but showing the piecewise model estimated by the segmented() function:

[image]

Of course, once this issue is resolved, I need to calculate the depth associated with the breakpoint, so please let me know if you have ideas for how to do this. Note that I don't actually care about accurately modeling the data with a piecewise function, I really only care about identifying the thermocline.

Here are the data (published to the web from Google Sheets): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQnD_zliGwEOC2Wpo6Rxi3tmzB562W0_MPEsU_MuQmjqit3v61ClS5BsJfnyz5OD8pY5pwya07uE6or/pubhtml

Comment: This question is more statistical in nature than programming-related. I voted to have it moved to the Cross-Validated forum.

Comment: Agreed that it's suitable for stats.stackexchange.com. It looks to me like you could consider switching the dependent and independent variables before looking for the break point -- the results you showed have the break point stated in degrees, but you want it in depth, right? Maybe you could plot the variables the other way around too, right? I.e. look at temperature as a function of depth instead of vice versa. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!! Would you please clarify the difference for me?